# Check the validity of a domain name

Tags: ios, swift, validation, url

I need to make sure that a URL that the user inputs goes where it should go. I mean if the user inputs "http://google.com/blablabla" or "http://google123.com/blablabla". I need to figure out that the second url is not correct because it won't open google's web-site. Is there some method in Swift to do that? Or do I just need to check if the URL contains "http://google.com"?

Comment: @MartinR Google was gust as example. User inputs some url in to textfield and i need to check if the url goes to the concrete web-site or not. In my example the concrete web-site was Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Malformed URL**

To verify whether or not the URL itself is malformed, let the OS do it:
(check that the URL has all the parts it needs, namely a [scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes) and a host)

```swift
if let url = URL(string: rawStringInput),
    let _ = url.scheme,
    let _ = url.host {
    // rawStringInput is well formed
}
```

You can then query all sorts of information from the URL, such as scheme (*http*), the host (*google.com)*, the path (*blablabla*), fragment, port and so on.

**2. Valid URL**

If you want to know whether or not the URL is reachable (i.e. the remote server responds to it), you actually need to execute the request.

Comment: What do .scheme and . host do ?

Comment: Good point. Made a edit to the response. The idea is to let the OS parse the `rawInputString`, and test against a non-null scheme like `http` or `https` plus a non null host. In addition, you can verify against *blablabla" by looking at the path.

Comment: Thank very much, host method is exactly what i was looking for!